# SQL SELECT complex expression in column - additional boolean

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I seem to have reached a mental block on this and hope someone can give me a kick in the right direction.

I have a web application similar to a newsreader client. It's written in Python and uses SQLAlchemy but that's not important here as I'm trying to get my head around the SQL, also I'm using SQLite as a backend.

There is a Users table and an Articles table, the Users table is obvious enough and the Articles table stores individual articles (like posts on a news server). I track which user has read which article through a many-many relationship employing another table, Users_Articles, to do this.

The (cut down) schema is something like this:

```
Users:
  user_id
  user_name

Articles:
  article_id
  article_body

Users_Articles:
  user_id
  article_id
```

What I'm trying to do is SELECT a list of articles but to also display which article has already been read by the current user thus I'd like to add a boolean column to the set of columns in the SELECT statement which indicates if there is a row in Users_Articles which refers to the article for the current user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can go with left outer join

```
select 
a.article_id, a.article_body, 
ua.article_id as as been_read --will be not null for read articles
from Articles a 
left outer join Users_Articles ua 
    on (ua.article_id = a.article_id and ua.user_id = $current_user_id)
```

or with subselect

```
select 
a.article_id, a.article_body, 
(select 1 from Users_Articles ua 
    where ua.article_id = a.article_id 
    and ua.user_id = $current_user_id) as been_read --will be not null for read articles
from Articles a
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, pretty much straightforward but for some reason I couldn't get my mind around it.